# Draw lines on jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, draw, graphics2d

I want to make it like [Draw a ruler (line with tick marks at 90 degree angle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488419/java-draw-a-ruler-line-with-tick-marks-at-90-degree-angle) just not on jframe but on jpanel.

So I tried:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
JPanel ff = new JPanel();

ff.add(new JComponent() {
...
});

f.add(ff);
...
```

but I failed. :(
How to?

Comment: Make sure your component actually shows. Like ff.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); or something.

Comment: Possible doup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673056/java-drawing-on-jpanel-which-on-a-jframe

Comment: It isn't solution. I have already tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply override `paintComponent(Graphics g){}` for ff and draw your within that method.

i.e.

```
JPanel ff = new JPanel(){ 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        // Draw what you want to appear on your JPanel here.
        // g.drawLine(blah blah blah), etc.
    }
};
```

In which case you have no need for this...

```
ff.add(new JComponent() {
    ...
});
```

You don't need this generic component unless you want to implement the custom component as suggest in the link you provided. In the case that you do want to create such a custom component, then you don't need `ff`, since a JFrame is already a container that can hold your component.

Comment: @mike - Could also suggest call `super.paintComponent` - only because a good number of questions that get asked are fixed by adding an appropriate call to `super.paintXxx` ;)