# Java drawLine() not working in netBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to draw a line in java , I work by netBeans , 
I followed this tuto https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzFmfbXghj4 , 
For I did not show my form !

the code :

```
panel1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    Graphics g =  panel1.getGraphics();
    System.out.println(panel1.getWidth());
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 60, 600);
    panel1.show();
```

Full code , ( what is the problem and how to resolved that ? ):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication6;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

/**
 *
 * @author brm17
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {

        initComponents();
     panel1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        Graphics g =  panel1.getGraphics();
        System.out.println(panel1.getWidth());
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 60, 600);
        panel1.show();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        panel1 = new java.awt.Panel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel1);
        panel1.setLayout(panel1Layout);
        panel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 688, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        panel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 528, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(panel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(panel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private java.awt.Panel panel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: This is not the proper way of painting inside a JPanel. That way the line will just disappear each time the UI refreshes. And it does refresh when you call `show`. So you need to move that call after the panel has been shown. But again, this is the wrong way to do it. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164392/draw-lines-on-jpanel)

Comment: Please read: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to see how to do Swing Graphics correctly.