# Clearing drawings on Jframe

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I am making a game in which I move a square with my mouse, but when I move my mouse the old squares do not delete, which results in a trail of squares. I would like it to only have the one square which is following my mouse. This is currently my code. I have read to use paintcomponents but I am not sure how to use it since I am still a beginner.

This is in my "GamePanel" Class

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m) {

        Graphics g= this.getGraphics();
        h.changeX(m.getX());
        h.changeY(m.getY());
        h.drawHero(g);

    }
```

This is in my "Hero" Class

```
public void drawHero(Graphics g){

        g.drawImage(heroPic,stX,stY,null); //heroPic is a picture I imported
```

Comment: Don't draw directly on `JFrame`. Use `JPanel` to draw on it. 
Find a sample code here [How to draw in jPanel? (swing/graphics Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118737/how-to-draw-in-jpanel-swing-graphics-java?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: _"I have read to use `paintcomponents`"_ - Actually you want `paintComponent`, no `s`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `this.getGraphics()`. That is something you will definitely not want to to do, since it produces artifacts (as you mentioned).

It would be better to store the mouse position as a variable, then handle all the rendering when the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method has been called. Be sure to also call `super.paintComponent(Graphics)` to get rid of artifacts.

Generally, you should only handle graphics inside the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method and in any methods that are called only from the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.

---

Here is a question which touches on why you should avoid `Component#getGraphics()`: [Drawing an object using getGraphics() without extending JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986677/drawing-an-object-using-getgraphics-without-extending-jframe)

---

Here is another question I answered revolving around rendering with graphics: [Java JFrame draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122492/java-jframe-draw/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a seperate class that extends JPanel :

```
class DrawPane extends JPanel {
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(heroPic, x, y, this);

 }


}
```

Then create a variable that will hold this class object :

```
DrawPane dp = new DrawPane();
```

after that set the variable to the contence pane. :

```
JFrame.setContencePane(dp);
```

Now to repaint this do :

```
 dp.repaint();
```

Do not worry about the 'Graphics g' you wont have to input anything.

Comment: `g.drawImage(heroPic, x, y, null);` should be `g.drawImage(heroPic, x, y, this);`.  A `JPanel` **is an** `ImageObserver`.